# can a web user delete the firestore offline cache or a local database by clearing browser history

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

With Google Chrome and a Flutter web app using Firebase Firestore, when you clear browsing data there are a number of options you can select for deletion.  By default, "site settings" and "hosted app data" are deselected.  If these are enabled for deletion, will this result in the Firestore offline cache being deleted?

Also if "shared-preferences" or indexeddb or the "hive" database are used for local storage by the web app, will any of these be affected by a user clearing browser data?

If the answer to any of the above is yes, will it make any difference if the web app is a Progressive Web App that the user has installed for offline use?  I want my web app to be useable when the user doesn't have an internet connection but I also want to minimize Firestore reads and network traffic when the web app starts up by using the local cache and timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, "site settings" and "hosted app data" are deselected. If these are enabled for deletion, will this result in the Firestore offline cache being deleted?

Yes, it will be deleted. Remember that offline persistence is also called disk persistence.

> If the answer to any of the above is yes, will it make any difference if the web app is a Progressive Web App that the user has installed for offline use?

Firestore is designed to be used online, for real-time capabilities, not *only* offline. It is designed as an online database that can work offline even for longer periods of time. As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, "Firestore SDKs nowadays implement indexes on their offline data making access to them more predictable and scaleable, and it stores snapshots of the data with pending writes, making it much more suitable for longer offline usage."

> I want my web app to be useable when the user doesn't have an internet connection but I also want to minimize Firestore reads and network traffic when the web app starts up by using the local cache and timestamps.

It will work offline if you [enable offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) because, for the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the `enablePersistence` method.

If you want to read only from the cache, then you can [indicate the source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) to be the cache.

Comment: "Firestore is designed to be used online for real-time capabilities, not offline. It is really designed as an online database that can work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected, not used as an offline database." This is actually no longer true. Firestore SDKs nowadays implements indexes on its offline data making access to them more predictable and scaleable, and it stores snapshots of the data with pending writes, making it much more suitable for longer offline usage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, puf. I just updated my answer and I quote you.

Comment: Hey Alpha. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?